# How to import SQL data into marketing cloud?

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, sql, marketing-cloud-connect

good afternoon everyone.

My client would like to import SQL data from his database to the marketing cloud

from what I've been searching I found just this (https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_es_import_into_de.htm&type=5) where it could only be done by FTP or import directly from the computer

are there other ways to do this?

Comment: Please add some contexte. What are those "SQL datas" ? Where do you want import them, Lists, Data Extensions ?

Comment: good afternoon Perret, the client would like to bring this data to data extensions in MC

Answer (score 1):

There are 5 ways of ingesting data into data extensions in SFMC:

1. Import via sFTP by dropping the file in the sFTP and using an import activity in Automation Studio
2. Import via the UI by clicking the "Import" button and uploading the file
3. Synchronized data extensions through the Marketing Cloud Connector
4. Via API
5. Manually entering in data in Contact Builder (not recommended)

I would recommend the first two options above.